# Meteor: Modify collection on client side only

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a server side collection to which I subscribe on the client side. The client does not have write access to the server side collection.

I would like to modify the collection on the client side only and destroy that change when I stop the subscription/move to another route.

Is that possible somehow?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: how about client only side Collection? ClientCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);

Answer (score 0):

I would use a transformation on the client, like this:

```js
var Books = new Meteor.Collection('books', {
    transform: function(doc){

        /*
            A doc looks like this:
            {
                _id: "...",
                title: "A nice title..."
            }
        */

        doc.clientTitle = new ReactiveVar("")

        doc.setClientTitle = function(title){
            this.clientTitle.set(title)
        }

        doc.getTitle = function(){
            var clientTitle = this.clientTitle.get()
            if(clientTitle == ""){
                return this.title
            }else{
                return clientTitle
            }
        }

    }
})
```

and then use `theBook.getTitle()` to get the title and `theBook.setTitle('The new title')` to update it on the client only.

Note: `ReactiveVar` comes from the package `reactive-var`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That would probably work, but would be a lot of code it I have many attributes in my collection (which I do). Isn't there a more elegant way.